# Set frame for subview of tableHeaderView of UITableView disables UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, subview

I have this problem.

Let's have:

```
[wrapper addSubview:_headerView]; // _headerView contains UIButton
```

There is:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = wrapper;
```

And it works fine if table is scrolled to top. If I scroll in this table down and up, I set new frame for `_headerView` because I have to have it visible for some situations.

But here come problems: `UIButton` from `_headerView` does not react for my gestures.

Can anybody help?

**Edit**

After running:

```
po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

It returns:

```
<UIWindow: 0x165a9290; frame = (0 0; 320 480); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x165ab6c0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x165a77d0>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x1656dfc0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x165ce2c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x165b2d80>>
   |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x165384c0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x165eb9e0>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x167551a0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1675a160>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x1653df80; frame = (0 64; 320 416); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x165b90b0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UITableView: 0x16c2aa00; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16531630>; layer = <CALayer: 0x165f01b0>; contentOffset: {0, 844.5}>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x167575d0; frame = (0 0; 320 416); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x16528700>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <BazarAdCell: 0x167981d0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 793; 320 94); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x16798380>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x1679ae30; frame = (0 0; 320 94); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1679b0c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679b000>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x1679ad10; frame = (15 93; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x1679ad80>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x167983b0; frame = (0 0; 320 93.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1679b6a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x16798420>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x16798450; frame = (6 6; 108 81); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167984d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x16798500; frame = (120 73; 192 14); text = '13 990  €'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167985b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x16798880; frame = (8 8; 26 14); text = 'TOP'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16798930>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x16798dd0; frame = (120 7; 192 16); text = 'Opel Insignia kombi 2.0 C...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+H+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16798e80>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x16799070; frame = (120 44; 192 27); text = 'combi, manuálna prevodovk...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16799120>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x167994e0; frame = (120 74; 88 14); text = 'Dnes'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16799460>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x16799760; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (120 26; 35 15); text = 'diesel'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x16799810>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x16799d20; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (159 26; 37 15); text = 'r.2010'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x16799dd0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1679a2a0; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (200 26; 64 15); text = '155 000 km'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679a350>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1679a790; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (268 26; 21 15); text = 'KE'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679a840>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x1679c560; frame = (6 93.5; 314 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x1679c480>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <BazarAdCell: 0x16776040; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 887; 320 94); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x165ca0f0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x167761f0; frame = (0 0; 320 94); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1676fa80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1676f9e0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x167749a0; frame = (15 93; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x16774a10>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x1674cf90; frame = (0 0; 320 93.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1653c080>; layer = <CALayer: 0x165ca710>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x16773af0; frame = (6 6; 108 81); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x165ca740>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x16760150; frame = (120 73; 192 14); text = '9 999  €'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16770650>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1674d420; frame = (8 8; 26 14); text = 'TOP'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677bbb0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1677aa70; frame = (120 7; 192 16); text = 'Seat Leon 1.9 TDI 105k Ec...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+H+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1674d8f0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x167550c0; frame = (120 44; 192 27); text = 'hatchback, manuálna prevo...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x165f5440>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1652f4d0; frame = (120 74; 88 14); text = 'Dnes'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677c0a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1674ff10; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (120 26; 35 15); text = 'diesel'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1674ef60>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1677a5b0; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (159 26; 37 15); text = 'r.2010'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677a660>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1652acc0; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (200 26; 58 15); text = '99 000 km'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x1674ea90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1674a620; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (262 26; 22 15); text = 'BB'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x1674a6d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x16755bd0; frame = (6 93.5; 314 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x16755af0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <BazarAdCell: 0x1677e550; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 981; 320 94); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677e700>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x16781920; frame = (0 0; 320 94); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16781bb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x16781af0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x16781800; frame = (15 93; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x16781870>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x1677e730; frame = (0 0; 320 93.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16782190>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677e7a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1677e7d0; frame = (6 6; 108 81); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677e850>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1677e880; frame = (120 73; 192 14); text = '2 000  €'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677f0b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1677f370; frame = (8 8; 26 14); text = 'TOP'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677f420>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1677f8c0; frame = (120 7; 192 16); text = 'Peugeot 607 2.2 HDi Excel...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+H+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677f970>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1677fb60; frame = (120 44; 192 27); text = 'sedan / Liftback, manuáln...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677fc10>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1677ffd0; frame = (120 74; 88 14); text = 'Dnes'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677ff50>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x16780250; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (120 26; 35 15); text = 'diesel'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x16780300>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x16780810; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (159 26; 37 15); text = 'r.2004'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x167808c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x16780d90; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (200 26; 64 15); text = '175 000 km'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x16780e40>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x16781280; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (268 26; 21 15); text = 'BA'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x16781330>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x16784010; frame = (6 93.5; 314 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x16783f30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <BazarAdCell: 0x16793100; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 1263; 320 94); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x167932b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x16795d60; frame = (0 0; 320 94); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16795ff0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x16795f30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x16795c40; frame = (15 93; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x16795cb0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x167932e0; frame = (0 0; 320 93.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x167965d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x16793350>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x16793380; frame = (6 6; 108 81); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16793400>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x16793430; frame = (120 73; 192 14); text = '4 000  €'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167934e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x167937b0; frame = (8 8; 26 14); text = 'TOP'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16793860>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x16793d00; frame = (120 7; 192 16); text = 'UAZ Diesel 2,4'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+H+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16793db0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x16793fa0; frame = (120 44; 192 27); text = 'SUV / Off-road, manuálna ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16794050>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x16794410; frame = (120 74; 88 14); text = 'Dnes'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16794390>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x16794690; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (120 26; 35 15); text = 'diesel'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x16794740>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x16794c50; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (159 26; 37 15); text = 'r.2011'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x16794d00>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x167951d0; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (200 26; 58 15); text = '75 000 km'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x16795280>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x167956c0; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (262 26; 22 15); text = 'PO'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x16795770>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x16797370; frame = (6 93.5; 314 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x16797290>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <BazarAdCell: 0x167a27e0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 1169; 320 94); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a2990>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x167a67e0; frame = (0 0; 320 94); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x167a6a70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a69b0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x167a66c0; frame = (15 93; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x167a6730>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x167a29c0; frame = (0 0; 320 93.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x167a7050>; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a2a30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x167a2a60; frame = (6 6; 108 81); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a2ae0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x167a2b10; frame = (120 73; 192 14); text = '3 400  €'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a2bc0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x167a2e90; frame = (8 8; 26 14); text = 'TOP'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a2f40>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x167a33e0; frame = (120 7; 192 16); text = 'Škoda Octavia 1.9 TDI Col...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+H+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a3490>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x167a3680; frame = (120 44; 192 27); text = 'sedan / Liftback, manuáln...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a3730>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x167a3af0; frame = (120 74; 88 14); text = 'Dnes'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a3a70>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x167a3d70; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (120 26; 35 15); text = 'diesel'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a3e20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x167a4330; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (159 26; 37 15); text = 'r.2001'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a43e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x167a48b0; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (200 26; 64 15); text = '230 000 km'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a4960>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x167a6140; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (268 26; 22 15); text = 'NR'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a61f0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x167a80f0; frame = (6 93.5; 314 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x167a8010>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <BazarAdCell: 0x1679d3b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 1075; 320 94); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679d560>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x167a0010; frame = (0 0; 320 94); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x167a02a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a01e0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x1679fef0; frame = (15 93; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x1679ff60>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x1679d590; frame = (0 0; 320 93.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x167a0880>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679d600>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1679d630; frame = (6 6; 108 81); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679d6b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1679d6e0; frame = (120 73; 192 14); text = '1 550  €'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+W+RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679d790>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1679da60; frame = (8 8; 26 14); text = 'TOP'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679db10>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1679dfb0; frame = (120 7; 192 16); text = 'Hyundai H1 2,5 TD 6 miest'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+H+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679e060>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1679e250; frame = (120 44; 192 27); text = 'van, 5-st. manuálna prevo...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679e300>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1679e6c0; frame = (120 74; 88 14); text = 'Dnes'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679e640>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1679e940; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (120 26; 35 15); text = 'diesel'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679e9f0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1679ef00; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (159 26; 37 15); text = 'r.2000'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679efb0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1679f480; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (200 26; 64 15); text = '304 000 km'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679f530>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TagLabel: 0x1679f970; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (268 26; 20 15); text = 'ZA'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x1679fa20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x167a1990; frame = (6 93.5; 314 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x167a18b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x165ba1b0; frame = (0 412.5; 320 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1674f1a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x167f0040; frame = (0 844.5; 320 1); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x16584f90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x16733780; frame = (0 1259.5; 320 1); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1678b030>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x167cc730; frame = (0 0; 320 40); layer = <CALayer: 0x16533630>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x165c02f0; frame = (0 844.5; 320 40); layer = <CALayer: 0x167ac250>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x167ebdd0; frame = (10 4; 97.678 32); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167d1740>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x167f2270; frame = (-1 7; 98 17); text = 'Zmeniť kritériá'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167e6de0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x1670ff70; frame = (280 5; 30 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1675d450>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x165dd010; frame = (0 0; 30 30); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167976b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1674ebe0; frame = (314.5 928; 3.5 40); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16761070>>
   |    | <UINavigationBar: 0x165b89e0; frame = (0 20; 320 44); autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16503290>; layer = <CALayer: 0x165b2c00>>
   |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackground: 0x1653a8b0; frame = (0 -20; 320 64); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1656e180>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x165e6d40; frame = (0 64; 320 0.5); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x165f44c0>>
   |    |    | <UIView: 0x16753b40; frame = (44.5 0; 209.5 44); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1676cbf0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1655fa30; frame = (0 0; 209 44); autoresize = W+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1676d120>>
   |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x165b2960; frame = (0 4; 209 20); text = 'Osobné autá'; autoresize = LM+W+RM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x165258a0>>
   |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x167557c0; frame = (0 20; 209 20); text = '50 833 inzerátov'; autoresize = LM+W+RM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16755870>>
   |    |    | <UIView: 0x1652de30; frame = (260 0; 44 44); autoresize = H; layer = <CALayer: 0x165f0800>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x16770050; frame = (0 0; 44 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = H; layer = <CALayer: 0x165c25d0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1674c490; frame = (-13 -28; 100 100); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1886548836; layer = <CALayer: 0x16753630>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1677bd70; frame = (23 8; 28 28); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1677bdf0>>
   |    |    | <UINavigationButton: 0x167a4d20; frame = (2.5 6; 36 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a4e50>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x167a5c90; frame = (8.5 4; 13.5 22); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x167a4cf0>>
   |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView: 0x165c0470; frame = (8 12; 12.5 20.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1655a8c0>>
   |    | <UIToolbar: 0x165bbd60; frame = (0 480; 320 44); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x165bbe00>>
   |    |    | <_UIToolbarBackground: 0x165bbfa0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x165bbee0>>
   |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropView: 0x1676a350; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UIBackdropViewLayer: 0x16550b20>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x16756aa0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x165e5a50>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x16768680; frame = (0 0; 320 44); alpha = 0.98; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1652a530>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x165bc1a0; frame = (0 -0.5; 320 0.5); autoresize = W+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x165bc220>>
```

Comment: Can you launch the app and scroll the table view to make uibutton not respond and then pause the app using debugger, run this line po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription] and paste the output in your post please. This allows you to inspect the view hierarchy.

Comment: Can you set different color for your uibutton and header view and check if the button is appeared in the header view..You might be tested with this approach?

Comment: Button appears, but is not active. I cannot tap on it.

Comment: Probabily your button is below to any other view which is clear color can you explore your code for wrapper, headerview and button creation?

Comment: wrapper is UIView with subview called _headerView. _headerView has subviews: two UIButtons. Nothing more, nothing less. They are tapable, if table is scrolled up.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot please ?

Comment: I have solved it. When I want to show _headerView, I simple add it as subview of self.view. When I do not want it, I do removeFromSuperview. Thank you all.